# Issue form document.forms[0].submit

Tags: html, forms

I want to auto submit the form through the function that I call onload but submit button creates an extra parameter, see the URL "http://somewebsite/webapp/file.php?password_new=&password_conf=&action=change".

```html
<html>
<body onload='document.forms[0].submit();'>
 
<form action="http://somewebsite/webapp/file.php" method="GET" style="display:block">
        
        <p><label for="password_new">New password:</label><br />
        <input type="password" id="password_new" name="password_new" value="432"></p>

        <p><label for="password_conf">Re-type new password:</label><br />
        <input type="password" id="password_conf" name="password_conf" value="432"></p>  

        <button type="submit" name="action" value="change">Change</button> 
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

```
<html>
```

New password:

Re-type new password:

Change

Comment: Replace the submit button with a hidden field with the same name and value, then submitting the form via JS will get you the same result. (Or trigger a click on the button, instead of calling the submit method.)

Comment: Give a name to a from like myForm and try to submit using   document.forms["myForm"].submit()